DensityPlot with parameter
I want to plot temperature profile for shadow radius. So here is my code.
f[r_] := 1 - (2*M)/r + Q^2/r^2 + (8*Pi*P*r^2)/3;
mass = (3*Q^2 + 3*r^2 + 8*P*Pi*r^4)/(6*r); 
T[r_] := (-Q^2 + r^2 + 8*P*Pi*r^4)/(4*Pi*r^3)
veff[r_] := f[r]/r^2
R[t_] := Last[r /. NSolve[t == T[r] /. {M -> 1, Q -> 0.5, P -> 0.1}, r, Reals]]
rp1[t_] := Last[r /. NSolve[D[veff[r], r] == 0, r, Reals] /. M -> mass /. r -> R[t]]
rs1[t_] := rp1[t]/Sqrt[f[rp1[t]]] /. {M -> 1, Q -> 0.5, P -> 0.1}
data = Table[With[{t = RandomReal[{0, 5}], \[Theta] = RandomReal[{0, 2*Pi}]}, {rs1[t]*Cos[\[Theta]], rs1[t]*Sin[\[Theta]], t}], {10^4}]; 
ListDensityPlot[data, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]

Now This gives the following picture
My question is, How can I use density plot instead of List density plot for this plotting as it takes too much time to create data? I Also want to improve my diagram by adding bar legend for t and labeling id by 'T'.
edit- I also want to use different colour. For eg. I want to blend some deep blue, brown and red to show different region for fixed t.

edit-
Here is an alternative way i am trying-
f[r_] := 1 - (2*M)/r + Q^2/r^2 + (8/3)*Pi*P*r^2
mass = (3*Q^2 + 3*r^2 + 8*P*Pi*r^4)/(6*r) /. r -> rh
T[r_] := (-Q^2 + r^2 + 8*P*Pi*r^4)/(4*Pi*r^3)
rp = (r /. Last[NSolve[D[veff[r], r] == 0, r]]) /. M -> mass;
min = First[FindMinimum[T[rh] /. {Q -> 0.5, P -> 0.1} && 0 < rh < 1, {rh, 0.6}]
max = First[FindMaximum[T[rh] /. {Q -> 0.5, P -> 0.1} && 0 < rh < 1, {rh, 0.6}]]
colorf1 = Blend[{{min, Yellow}, {max, Red}}, #1] & ;
bl = BarLegend[{colorf1, {min, max}}, 10, LegendMarkerSize -> 300, LegendLabel -> Style["legend", 20, "Panel"]];
pl = ParametricPlot[{rs*Cos[\[Theta]], rs*Sin[\[Theta]]} /. {M -> 1.2, Q -> 0.5, P -> 0.1}, {rh, 0, 1}, {\[Theta], 0, 2*Pi}, PlotStyle -> colorf1]
plot = Legended[pl, Placed[bl, Right]]

This gives the following figure.

I have plotted region bounded by concentric circle of radius 'rs', which is a function of 'rh'. Now I want to show the corresponding values of T in bar legend. The bar legend part is ok but the plot does not show the corresponding color for T values. for same rh, the color corresponding to T should show in the plot. Can anyone fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Is this somehow connected to your previous question? Are you looking to obtain the same plot? Nevertheless, it is not really clear what is going on. Don't you just need a polar density plot? For example: DensityPlot[T[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] /. {M -> 1, Q -> 0.5, P -> 0.1}, {x, y} ∈ Disk[{0, 0}, 1.3], PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> {-1, 0.5}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]

If this is not it, then please edit the question and explain a bit more thoroughly what you are plotting and why you are taking random points ... :)

@Domen Thank you for the response today and yesterday. Yes, This is connected to my previous question. I am Plotting X^2+y^2=r^2 here r is a function t, rs1[t] in the code. for different t we get different radius r. So I want to density plot for a range {t,0,5} say.

Alright, for the future cases, it would be better to edit the old question instead of opening a new one :) Anyways, are you aware that your rs1[t] is not an injective function? You get the same r for different values of t: Plot[rs1[t], {t, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"t", "r"}]]

rs1[t] is injective in {0,0.2} but for t in {0,1} its not. different t might give same rs1

@Domen Can you please look at the edited version?

I wanted to help with your question, but I got lost in your code. It would help if you explained in mathematical terms and equations what problem exactly are you solving. As for your updated code: You should use ColorFunction instead of PlotStyle. And you should also probably change your colorf1. The arguments are given as x, y, r_s, θ. If you use #1, you are coloring by x. You probably want to do colorf1 = Blend[{{min, Yellow}, {max, Red}}, T[#3] /. {Q -> 0.5, P -> 0.1}] &;
